# counting -99.9 in r

Tags: r

I am new in using R and I have a question for which I am trying to find the answer. I have  a file organized as follows (it has thousands of rows but I just show a sample for simplicity):

```
YEAR   Month  day    S1      T1     T2         R1
1965    3       2    11.7    20.6    11.1    18.8
1965    3       3    14.0    16.7     3.3     0.0
1965    3       4   -99.9   -99.9   -99.9   -99.9
1965    3       5     9.2     5.6     0.0   -99.9
1965    3       6    10.1     6.7     0.0   -99.9
1965    3       7     9.7     7.2     1.1     0.0
```

I would like to know for each column (T1, T2, and R1) in which Year, Month and Day the -99.9 are located; e.g. from 1980/1/3 to 1980/1/27 there are X -99.9 for T1, from 1990/2/10 to 1990/3/30 there are Y-99.9 for T1....and so on. Same for T2, and R. 
How can do this in R?

This is only one file like this but I have almost 2000 files with the same problem (I know I need to loop it) but if I know how to do it for one file then I will just create a loop.

I really appreciate any help. Thank you very much in advance for reading and helping!!!

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty of renaming your last  dataframe column "R1"

```
 lapply(c('T1', 'T2', 'R1'), function(x) { dfrm[ dfrm[[x]]==-99.9 , # rows to select
                                               1:3 ] }# columns to return
        )
#-------------    
[[1]]
  YEAR Month day
3 1965     3   4

[[2]]
  YEAR Month day
3 1965     3   4

[[3]]
  YEAR Month day
3 1965     3   4
4 1965     3   5
5 1965     3   6
```

It wasn't clear whether you wanted the values or counts (and I don't think you can have both in the same report.) If you wanted to name the entries:

```
> misdates <- .Last.value
> names(misdates) <- c('T1', 'T2', 'R1')
```

If you wanted a count:

```
 lapply(misdates, NROW)
$T1
[1] 1

$T2
[1] 1

$R1
[1] 3
```

(You might want to learn how to use NA values. Using numbers as missing values is not recommended data management.)

Comment: re last comment, using `na.strings="-99.9" when reading in the data might be useful ...

Comment: I agree regarding the NA, in fact I have done that. I would like to ask you about the misdates <- .Last.value   "value" will be my -99.9 (or NA)? 
Thank you again for your help!

Comment: `.Last.value` would be the whole list created by `lapply(.)`  ... assuming you had not made another assignment in the meantime. Sometimes `.Last.value` is a really big dataframe. It's a sort of safety net when you forgot to make an assignment of an object to a name,

Comment: DWin thank you very much for the answer. I see the point. I will try the function again and see how it goes. My really worry is that I have more than 2000 rows (and 2000 files.....) and I might really need to have something that tells me from 1981/1/23 to 1981/1/30 there are -99.9; 1982/2/10 there is -99.9; 1990/10/20 to 1990/11/2 there are -99.9 and so on. As you can see it is quite a big job but I think in R it can be done. The only thing is that I am very new to R and therefore I find it hard to get to that point.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to obtain how many "-99.9"s you get per month AND by column,

Here's my code for S1 using `plyr`. You'll note that I expanded your example to get one more month of data.

```
library(plyr)

my.table <-read.table(text="YEAR Month day S1 T1 T2 R1
1965 3 2 11.7 20.6 11.1 18.8
1965 3 3 14.0 16.7 3.3 0.0
1965 3 4 -99.9 -99.9 -99.9 -99.9
1965 3 5 9.2 5.6 0.0 -99.9
1965 3 6 10.1 6.7 0.0 -99.9
1965 3 7 9.7 7.2 1.1 0.0
1966 1 7 -99.9 7.2 1.1 0.0
1966 1 8 -99.9 7.2 1.1 0.0
", header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE,sep = " ")

#Create a year/month column to summarise per month
my.table$yearmonth <-paste(my.table$YEAR,"/",my.table$Month,sep="")

S1 <-count(my.table[my.table$S1==-99.9,],"yearmonth")
S1
  yearmonth freq
1    1965/3    1
2    1966/1    2
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I also put the day, so I have yearmonthday. This was very helpful thank you again! I am glad I am using this blog.